# No cold water and low hot water

Tags: water-pressure

Our toilet valve and the pipe behind the bathtub burst. We had those repaired and when we turned the water back on, we have low hot water pressure and no cold water upstairs. We can't find any more leaks. At first, we thought air was in the lines so we waited. Our basement then flooded, so we turned the water off. Every time we turn the water on now, the basement stays dry but we have no cold water upstairs and low hot water pressure. My adult son turned off several water vales when trying to locate the main shut off valve. Could he have shut off incorrectly?

Comment: Hot and cold water originate from the same place, the incoming water supply from your provider (or from a well with a pump). The supply line branches where water is supplied to your water heater. It is common for old valves, when manipulated, to remain partially or fully closed after you think you have opened them back up (they fail internally sometimes). You should try closing and reopening each valve that was touched, while watching flow. This might give you clues to the problem. You might need a plumber.

Comment: While you have a plumber there, have him replace any old gate valves with ball valves. https://homeguides.sfgate.com/plumbing-gate-valve-failure-87925.html

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with Jimmie fix it that some gate valves break when trying to open, I would be looking for a local valve that is turned off OR when the pipe broke and was repaired scale and possibly pieces of PFTE tape may have plugged the lines at the bath. I find this more often unless the home is pre 50's galvanized then it could be both.+

Comment: True, +1, except I didn't figure the tub, with such large ports in the valve and downstream of it, would be very susceptible to debris...

Comment: Waterless faucets and thermostatic valves usually have small ports.